# Intellij one line getter/setter/constructor prettify code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, format, ide, pretty-print

IntelliJ Idea sometimes shortens short constructors/getters and setters into one-liners. (It doesn't literally affect the code, its just a view thing in the ide)

I've tried to google how to stop IntelliJ from doing this, but all the answers I get is how TO DO this, not how undo this. (not explained how to undo this in the same articles)

Here is how the one-liner looks like (again not affecting the code itself, just changes the view in IntelliJ until you click to edit that code, it will display like the second image:

[one-liner that ide does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hYTW.png)

[how it looks when u go to edit it (how I want it to look by default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUL0Z.png)

Comment: So how do you enable it? I can't imagine that disabling it would be really different from enabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this should fix it. In case it's not, play with the settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I only know it in Android Studio, but that is based on Intellij so it should be something similar:

```
Settings >> Editor >> General >> Code Folding
```

And there is a check 'One-line methods'. Turn that off.